How to lock device in landscape orientation in view controller?
I want to lock orientation to landscape right and landscape left only in one view controller. I use this code in my view controller to do it:
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return false
}
    
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .landscape
}

But it doesn't work for me if I rotate device. What I do wrong?

i think you need to work with willtransition method in controller

in app delegate file declare variable
var orientationLock = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait

add below extension at bottom of app delegate
extension UIViewController {

func lockOrientation(_ orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask) {
    if let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
        delegate.orientationLock = orientation
    }
    if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
        self.setNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterfaceOrientations()
    }
}

func lockOrientation(_ allowOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask, andRotateTo rotateOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask) {
    self.lockOrientation(allowOrientation)
    if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
        UIViewController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()
        let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene
        windowScene?.requestGeometryUpdate(.iOS(interfaceOrientations: rotateOrientation))
        self.setNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterfaceOrientations()
    } else {
        UIDevice.current.setValue(rotateOrientation.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
        UINavigationController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()
    }
}

}
in Viewcontroller add below code, also add one button and create one IBOutlet and redirect to second viewcontroller
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.lockOrientation(.all)

}

@IBAction func onBtnClick(_ sender: Any) {
    let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondVC") as? SecondVC
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
}

}
in second viewcontroller add below code
import UIKit

class SecondVC: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.lockOrientation(.landscape, andRotateTo: .portrait)
}

}

I need that first controller support all orientations. But in second controller I need to support only landscape. In your code my second vc autorotate to landscape. But if I rotate simulator my interface return to portrait.

in iOS16+ maybe you can try to call setNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterfaceOrientations of UIViewController.
in addition, if you use NavigationController or UITabBarController, you also should set shouldAutorotate and supportedInterfaceOrientations as your UIViewController.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

You should set your shouldAutorotate to true as autorotation only happens into supported interface orientations, setting it to false will prevent your view controller from rotating to the landscape. Also cascades of parent view controllers may block your controller from the rotation - set breakpoints and make sure that those methods are being called. You also can force the orientation update by calling setNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterfaceOrientations(). If this one doesn't help try making sure that your VC is connected by parent/child relationship with your window's rootViewController and none of parent VCs is not taking interface rotation control away from your VC.
